# Designing artificial signals

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum

I'm trying to design a sample signal that has two "components". I want the signal to look like the upper left figure, with the two components shown on the right. The time frequency spectrum is shown in the bottom left.

[image: signal]

I'm using MATLAB to generate this signal, as I am running MATLAB code that uses these signals. I have been trying my heart out with a combination of chirps, sincs and cos functions, but I just can't for the life of me reproduce this sort of a spectrogram. What I have produced looks like this:

[image: my signal]

It's quite close I feel, but there is something missing. Can someone point me to a way to approach this?

**EDIT:**

This is the code I use:

```
fs = 5000;
x0 = 1;
t = -x0:1/fs:x0;
yi = cos(t).*sinc(t).*chirp(t,150,0.2,250,'quadratic'); 
yj = cos(t).*sinc(t).*chirp(t,50,0.4,150,'quadratic'); 
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(t,yi+yj)
subplot(2,2,2)
plot(t,yj)
subplot(2,2,3)
spectrogram(yi+yj,512,511,256,fs,'yaxis')
subplot(2,2,4)
plot(t,yi)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "missing." specifically? Is it that the two U-shaped "ridges" in your spectrogram don't look as sharp? Or that your signal envelope decays to zero near the edges?

Comment: I would like to seperate the two ridges further, and have the "tapering off" effect of the upper ridge in the higher frequencies.

Comment: Looks like the upper ridge is not a quadratic chirp. It's very hard to see in the first image, but is it shaped more like a cosine?

Comment: It is a quadratic chirp though, if you look at the edit I made. My understanding of signals is quite unpolished, so I may be doing something blatantly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below I have manually created chirps where the frequency does not increase linearly, but behaves in a cosine-shape, as suggested by Atul Ingle . This waveform resembles the shape of the lines in the spectrogram nicely.

```
fs = 5000;
x0 = 1;
t = -x0:1/fs:x0;
yi = cos(t).*sinc(t/1.5).*cos(2*pi*500*(1.8-cos(2.2*t)).*t); 
yj = cos(t).*sinc(t/1.5).*cos(2*pi*500*(0.85-0.5*cos(2.3*t)).*t); 
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(t,yi+yj)
subplot(2,2,2)
plot(t,yj)
subplot(2,2,3)
spectrogram(yi+yj,512,511,256,fs,'yaxis')
subplot(2,2,4)
plot(t,yi)
```

[image: Program output]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful. Can I read off the frequencies of the chirp at t0 and some t1 similarly to when I use the chirp function? I mean I can look at the spectrogram and can see that the lower one goes from ~200 to ~1000 in a matter of 1 second, and the upper goes from ~500 to ~2000 in the same timeframe. But can I intuitively understand your manual chirps in a way that let's me adjust them to the frequencies I'd like?

Comment: The expressions (500*(1.8-cos(2.2*t)) describes the instantaneuos frequency at time t. So, for t=0, the frequency would be 500*(1.8-1)=400, up to 500*(1.8-cos(2.2))=1940

Comment: Thank you. One further question, if I may: Does the signal shown in the original post seem real? Whenever I do a spectrogram on lower frequency signals (as shown in the original post) the spectrograms don't show clear ridges. For example [here](http://i.imgur.com/uDmj2YO.png), the chirp goes from 0.5Hz to 10Hz, but the y-axis of the spectrogram still goes into the kHz range. Is there some way I can adjust the resolution of the spectrogram to still show the frequency spectrum of these lower frequency chirps?

Comment: instead of the spectrogram function, you might consider wavelet transforms, which give you higher resolution in lower frequencies, but less time-resolution for these areas. in contrast, the spectrogramm is the STFT squared, having similar resolution among all times and frequencies.

Comment: You can also try a constant-Q spectrogram.